# How can I make my font larger in PHP?

Tags: php, fonts, size

I have a PHP file that gets some XML data, but the font displayed is too small.  I found I can increase it, but only to size 7.  Is there a way to make 90pt. font instead?

Here is what I have that only goes up to size 7:

```
 <font face="helvetica, arial" color="white" size="7">

 <?php 
     $mydata = simplexml_load_file('http://192.168.xx.xxx:yyyy/data.xml');

     echo '<p align="right">'.round($mydata->device[14]->value).'</p>';
     ?>

 </font>
```

Comment: please stop using <font> and learn css

Answer (score 1):

size="90pt"

Read about cascading style sheets for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.  I needed to add the following inside the paragraph tag:

```
 style="font-size: 90pt;"
```